# Is it possible to subcribe to a sentence of an epl module?

Tags: esper

I have deployed an epl module with the code:

```
 
      InputStream inputFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Temperature.epl");
        if (inputFile == null) {
            inputFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("etc/Temperature.epl");
        }
        if (inputFile == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find file 'Temperature.epl' in classpath or relative to classpath");
        }

        try {
            epService.getEPAdministrator().getDeploymentAdmin().readDeploy(inputFile, null, null, null);
            // subscribers Ok, tested before whith epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL ()
            // sentences ok, printed
            EPStatement statement;
            statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement("Monitor");
            System.out.println(statement.getText() + ";");
            statement.setSubscriber(new MonitorEventSubscriber());
            statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement("Warning");
            System.out.println(statement.getText() + ";");
            statement.setSubscriber(new WarningEventSubscriber());
            statement = epService.getEPAdministrator().getStatement("Error");
            System.out.println(statement.getText() + ";");
            statement.setSubscriber(new ErrorEventSubscriber());

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error deploying EPL from 'Temperature.epl': " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

I can get the sentences by statement.getText(), but the subscribers are not activated. What it's wrong?
I'm working with Esper 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your code uses the current classloader, you'd want to make sure the classloader is the same else you can get different engine instances.

Also have your code actually send an event to see if it matches since this code doesn't send events.